# Replace %variablename% with %MyVariable% in htm file

Tags: html, powershell, batch-file, ms-word, duplicates

How to edit a word document?

```
SET /p MyNewPig="Enter My New Pig's Name: "
POWERSHELL(Get-Content c:\temp\test.htm) -replace '\%MyNewPig%\]', '%MyNewPig%' | Set-Content c:\temp\test.htm
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd create a small PowerShell script, e.g.:

```
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $file    = '',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $search  = '',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $replace = '' 
      )

[Int32] $Local:intRc   = 0;

try {
    (Get-Content -LiteralPath $file).replace( $search, $replace ) | Out-File -LiteralPath $file;
    } #try
catch [System.Exception] {
    Write-Host -Object ( 'ERROR : Exception was "{0}".' -f $_.Exception.Message );
    $intRc = -1;
    } #catch

exit $intRc;
```

...and then call it, e.g.:

```
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file c:\xxxxxx\script.ps1 -file c:\yyyyy\test.txt -search "%OLD_NAME%" -replace "%NEW_NAME%"
```

Comment: I have two documents and each one of them uses similar information and variables.  I need to collect the variables from user input, and change the name on over 50 variables in just one of the documents.  what method is best used to replace the variables in one document and than in the next?